# Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation:
>   $$x \frac{dy}{dx} = y(3-y)$$
>   where $x=2$ when $y=2$, giving $y$ as a function of $x$.

Can someone solve this and then explain what the second line about $x=2$, $y=2$ means?

Comment: Solutions of differential equations generally depend on a specified initial value. (Compare to the case of taking antiderivatives of a function: you have to write $+C$ because there is a free constant in the expression. By specifying the value of the antiderivative you want at a point, you fix that constant uniquely.)

Comment: The second line just tells you that $y(2) = 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to "solve" the initial value problem:

$\begin{cases} x y^\prime (x) = y(x)\ (3-y(x)) \\ y(2)=2 \end{cases}$.

Your ODE has a *singular point* in $x=0$ (for the coefficient of the $y^\prime (x)$ term vanishes), hence if the IVP has a solution it will have not to be defined in $x=0$.

Put the ODE in *normal form*, i.e. rewrite:

$\displaystyle y^\prime (x) =\frac{y(x)\ (3-y(x))}{x}$;

the function $f(x,y):= \frac{y (3-y)}{x}$ is of class $C^\infty$ in $(x,y)\in \Big(]-\infty ,0[\cup ]0,+\infty[\Big)\times \mathbb{R}$, hence the *existence and uniqueness theorem* applies and your IVP has unique local solution $y(x)$ whose graph passes through the point $(2,2)$.

The solution $y(x)$ is continuous in a neighbourhood $I_1$ of $x=2$ (because it has to be differentiable to satisfy the ODE), hence the composite function $f(x,y(x))$ is continuous in $I_1$; as $y^\prime (x)=f(x,y(x))$, then $y^\prime (x)$ is continuous in $I_1$, therefore $y(x)$ is a $C^1$ function in $I_1$. But then $y^\prime (x)$ is of class $C^1$ in $I_1$, for the composite function $f(x,y(x))$ is of class $C^1$ (apply the *chain rule*); therefore $y(x)$ is of class $C^2$... *Bootstrapping*, you see that $y(x)$ is of class $C^\infty$ in the neighbourhood $I_1$ of the initial point $2$.

Moreover, the solution $y(x)$ is also strictly increasing in a neighbourhood of $2$: in fact, $y(2)=2>0$ hence by continuity you can find a neighbourhood $I_2\subseteq I_1$ of $2$ in which $0<y(x)<3$, so:

$\displaystyle y^\prime (x)=\frac{y(x)\ (3-y(x))}{x} >0$,

thus $y(x)$ increases strictly.

Now you have all the ingredients to *properly* solve your problem: in fact, in $I_2$ you can divide both sides of the ODE by $y(x)\ (3-y(x))$ and rewrite:

$\displaystyle \frac{y^\prime (x)}{y(x)\ (3-y(x))} =\frac{1}{x}$;

now fix a point $x \in I_2$ and integrate both sides from $2$ to $x$:

$\displaystyle \int_2^x \frac{y^\prime (t)}{y(t)\ (3-y(t))}\ \text{d} t =\int_2^x \frac{1}{t}\ \text{d} t$

(I've introduced a dummy variable in the integrals); now the RHside gives you $\ln x -\ln 2$, hence you have to work on the LHside. Keeping in mind that $y(t)$ is strictly monotone hence invertible in $I_2$, we can make the change of variable $\theta =y(t)$: as $y(2)=2$ and $\text{d} \theta = y^\prime (t)\ \text{d} t$, you get:

$\displaystyle \begin{split}\int_2^x \frac{y^\prime (t)}{y(t)\ (3-y(t))}\ \text{d} t &= \int_2^{y(x)} \frac{1}{\theta (3-\theta)}\ \text{d} \theta \\
&=\frac{1}{3} \ln \theta - \frac{1}{3} \ln (3-\theta) \Big|_2^{y(x)} \\
&=\frac{1}{3} \left(\ln y(x) -\ln (3-y(x)) -\ln 2\right)\end{split}$.

Therefore the solution to your problem is implicitly determined by the equation:

$\displaystyle \ln \left( \frac{y(x)}{3-y(x)}\right) = \ln \frac{x^3}{4}$,

i.e.:

$\displaystyle \frac{4y(x)}{3-y(x)}=x^3$.

The latter equation is a rational algebraic equation w.r.t. $y(x)$ and can be solved with the usual tools, which yield:

$\displaystyle y(x)=\frac{3x^3}{4+x^3}$.

There is more that can be said, e.g. how the local solution $y(x)$ can be extended to a maximal solution... But that's another story.

Comment: *another* story indeed! Despite the overkill, I am grateful for a formal discussion and solution. +1

Comment: @The Chaz: *My two cents*: I don't think it's an *overkill*... It is just the correct way of doing the exercise.

Comment: This belief is evident by the nature of your answer! I'll continue to appreciate your rigor while "monkeying around" in my own way ;)

Comment: @The Chaz: Thank you! And watch your steps while "monkeying around" ;D

Answer (score 0):

This is just an Initial Value Problem. You use the techniques you know to solve for the general solution. Here is a good resource: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx. 
More specifically, you should look at ["Separable Equations"](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx)

The general solution in this case will have one arbitrary constant. You use the I.V.P to solve for this constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy because it's separable variables. So solve $dy/(y(3-y))=dx/x$.

Comment: ... by integrating both sides, and then use the initial value to determine the constant of integration

Comment: The method you adopted for separating variables is usually called *urang-utang© method* by some funny mathematicians. They mock: "People using this method whitout knowing its fomal justification (if any!) resemble Orangutans using thing to make rudimental tools and messing with them"; in fact, the method is based on a totally unformal algebraic manipulation of differentials which is hard to formalize (hence it's almost meaningless).

Comment: @Pacciu: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation), and in particular, Mike Spivey's answer there.

Comment: @pac its not meaningless, just leave $y'$ alone, two functions (of $x$) are equal, so are their integrals (wrt $x$).

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks for the reference, but I already know the story ;D  @yoyo: There are people believing that, say, one can pass from $\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} x} =f(y)$ to $\text{d} y=f(x)\ \text{d} x$ by multiplying both sides by $\text{d} x$... But what's the meaning of this? How can a differential be considered as a number when **it is not a number** (for, it is just a symbol or a linear map)? This is what I was referring to when I wrote *unformal algebraic manipulation of differentials which is [...] almost meaningless*.

Comment: @lhf Would it be too much to ask that you solve it this way? I've been trying to find the solution this way for awhile, but it has borne no fruit.

Answer (score 0):

its a simple problem just using separation of variable $ \ xy'=y(y-3)$ now using separation of variable the we ge $ \ {dy} \over{y(y-3)} $=$\ {dx} \over{x}$ just using partial fraction  then $\ {1}\over{y(y-3)}$= $\ {A}\over{y}$+$\ {B}\over{(y-3)}$$\ {....>}$ eq (1) putting y=0,y=3 we get A=1/3,B=1/3  then putting in eq 1 and the integrated both side to get over solution interm of constant . then applying initial condition y(2)=2 to get c and then back substituited in general to get our required solution.