# Seperation of variables justification?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I haven't found a similar question on Math SE, but I may not have looked enough because I find it hard to believe someone hasn't already asked this. Anyways, here goes:

I'm studying mathematics, but one of the courses is a course on physics. So, since my university chooses not to give courses on differential equations until we have a solid knowledge of Algebra, Geometry, Analysis, Topology, etc., the physics course includes a small supplement on ODE's. To my dismay though, one of the first things we learned was that we could solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y)g(x)$$
By multiplying by $dx$ on both sides, dividing by $f(y
)$ and integrating on the left with respect to $x$, and on the right with respect to $x$. I have no clue how this even makes sense as $dy/dx$ and $dx$ or $dy$ in an integral are just notations. Could someone elaborate a justification for this process? As a side note, is there any way to discuss these things intrinsically? Or is it like calculus where we always talk about $f(x)$ and use the canonical basis?

Comment: Since you mention dividing by $f(x)$ only, I'm assuming you meant for $g$ to be a function of $t$, hence the edit. If you meant otherwise, let me know or feel free to roll-back the edit.

Comment: Oops, yes that's what I meant. Since you've pointed it out though I'll edit to use the usual notations.

Comment: Up to something you should justify by a uniqueness theorem, things are even easier: $\frac{1}{f(y)}\frac{dy}{dx}$ is seen as the derivative of $G \circ y$, where $G$ is a primitive of $1/f$. That's all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What am I doing when I separate the variables of a differential equation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation)

Comment: @Taro Ah, yes the answers there are satisfactory, thanks.

Comment: I still would like a comment on my last remark though.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y=y(x)$ has a differential as
$$dy=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}dx
\\ dy=f(x)g(y)dx$$
One more thing you could easily think of $dx$ as a small quantity in your courses not as a $1$-form as others do in differential forms.