# is this differential equation possible??

Tags: calculus

I know that I shouldn't see $dx/dt$  as a fraction.

But we do this:

$dy/dx=y$

$dy/y=dx$

$ln(y)=x+c$

And we can use $dx$ and $dt$ when modeling something like: change in volume of balloon while pumping air in constant rate -

$dv=i \cdot dt$

$dr=dv/(4\pi r^2)$

and we can use $dv$ as small change in volume over small time and do this:

$dr=i\cdot dt/(4\pi r^2)$

**But are these things possible? Do we encounter these? (I have just made up these equations, haven't seen them anywhere) and are we able to solve for $y$?**

$dy=x^2dx+5x$

$dy\cdot dx=6xy$

$(dy)^2=\ln(5dx)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What am I doing when I separate the variables of a differential equation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation)

Answer (score 0):

$dy, dx$ stands for differentials of the variables $y$ and $x$ respectively, similar to any other variable. It's an infinitesimal quantity, usually used in linear approximation to represent a change in the linearization of a function.