# When can I treat infinitesimals as numbers?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Even if many mathematicians don't like the notation, I have found in many rigorous math books things like

$\frac{dy}{dx}=Ay$

so

$\frac{dy}{y}=Adx$

What I don't understand is this: 
**under which conditions is ok to treat infinitesimal as numbers ?** (multiplying for example both sides of an equation by dx).

Edit:

Not only, **what allows me to integrate both sides of the last equation** ???

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21199/155629

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this rigorous you can introduce a number system similar to that of dual numbers, viz. $dx^2=0$. (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Automatic_differentiation_using_dual_numbers).) Depending on the calculus task at hand in more advanced examples, you might change these axioms slightly. For example, a metric $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ would use $dx^\mu dx^\nu dx^\rho=0$, while Brownian noise in stochastic calculus may be taken to satisfy $dW_t^2=dt,\,dW_t^3=0$.