# What Exactly is the Derivative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I think of $\frac{d}{dx}$ as a function or operation which we apply because it instructs us to take $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(f(a+h)-f(a))}{h} = f'(a)$; however, in differential equations or integration we just simply play around with $dx$ by moving it to the numerator. I'm confused. What exactly does it mean and what do the individual terms $ dx$ or $dy$ stand for without any denominator?

Comment: Moving the $dx$ around is not rigorous at all (in fact I advise not doing so). However, it serves as an intuition of "a nudge in the $x$ direction". So in derivatives $df/dx$ "measures" how much f wiggles as I nudge $x$. In integration, it is interpreted as how much area is under a curve on an interval of a "nudge in $x$". I think most of all $dx$ is just the intuitive analog to $\Delta x$ in the discrete version of calculus (slopes and sums) to the continuous version of calculus (instantaneous slopes and areas)

Comment: When undergrad differential equations textbooks do calculations that involve manipulating $dx$ and $dy$, you can always rephrase the calculations in a slightly different way to avoid treating $dx$ and $dy$ as separate quantities.

Comment: Where it works it is an application of the chain rule (for instance in the substitution rule of integration), which itself has this nice "cancellation" pattern in the Leibniz notation.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation and the linked questions there.