# Integrating both sides of an equation with respect to what?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, terminology

Let's say we have the following DE:

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = x $

**1.** That's how It could be solved:

$dy = x dx$

$\int{dy}=\int{xdx}$

$y=\frac{1}{2}x^2+c$

Is it mathematically correct to separate $dy$ and $dx$ ? Or it would appear as the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is a fraction which is not true.

**2.** Another method of writing the solution can be:

$\int\frac{dy}{dx} dx=\int{xdx}$

$\int{dy}=\int{xdx}$

$y=\frac{1}{2}x^2+c$

That's integrating the DE with respect to x. Is this mathematically correct? It seems like the $dx$ cancels each other in the LHS, but we are not allowed to treat this as a fraction.

**My Questions are:**

- Which of these ways of writing the solution is the most accurate?
- And which of these 2 is wrong in terms of following mathematical structure?
- When we integrate both sides of the equation, can we just put the integral sign without integrating with respect to a variable? (for example in case 1)

Comment: Third method should be $\int y'\,dx.$ If you made that change, all three methods are equally valid.

Comment: It is probably more correct to write $\int {dy(x) \over dx} dx = \int x dx$...

Comment: To justify the first method in full rigor, one needs to develop the theory of differential forms. But the upshot is that, all the manipulations in your solution can be validated.

Comment: The integral sign is very important as it defines the integration. It also tells us if it indefinite or definite.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation

Answer (score 1):

The first two are O.K. - the second being a more rigorous statement.
The third is wrong.  $\int y'dy \ne y$, since $y'\ne 1$.

I don't quite get what the third question asks.

Answer (score 0):

It is separable equation where $ y= y(x)$. Consider the problem
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=F(x)*Q(y)$$ where $F(x)$ depends only of $x$ and $Q(y)$ only of $y$.
If $Q(y) \neq 0$ we can rewrite this as
$$\frac{y'(x)}{Q(y(x))}= F(x)$$
$$\int_{x_0}^x{\frac{y'(t)}{Q(y(t))}dt}=\int_{x_0}^x{F(t)dt}$$
Then $y(t)=s$ We will get
$$\int_{y(x_0)}^{y(x)}{\frac{ds}{Q(s)}} = \int_{x_0}^x{F(t)dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

When your diffferential equation is separable you end up with a differential form  $$ f(y)dy = g(x) dx$$

Since you are assuming taht $$y=y(x)$$ you may integrate both sides  with respect to $x$ but the LHS has gone through a change of variable so we get   $$\int f(y(x))y'(x)dx = \int f(y)dy = \int g(x) dx$$

Thus the integration is valid.