# Consider the system $\dot{x}=4x^{2}-16$ find an analytical solution.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation, solution-verification, physics

I am working through a text book by [Strogatz Nonlinear dynamics and chaos](http://www.hds.bme.hu/%7Efhegedus/Strogatz%20-%20Nonlinear%20Dynamics%20and%20Chaos.pdf) . In chapter 2 question 2.2.1 , I am looking for an analytical solution. I have the question's answer but would like to ask how a certain step was performed.

#### Question

**Consider the system $\dot{x}=4x^{2}-16$ Find an analytical solution to the problem.**

#### Answer

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=4x^{2}-16
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{x^{2}-4} dx = \int 4 dt \\
\frac{1}{4} \ln(\frac{x-2}{x+2}) = 4t + C_{1} \\
x = 2 \frac{1 + C_{2}e^{16t}}{1 - C_{2}e^{16t}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
C_{2}(t=0) = \frac{x-2}{x+2}
\end{equation}

where $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are constants.

### Summary

In the first step to get to
$\int \frac{1}{x^{2}-4} dx = \int 4 dt $ how does this happen? There is an intermediary step/result that is not clear.  Any help would be really appreciated.

### Edit 1:

In other words, is this step okay?
\begin{equation}
\frac{\dot{x}}{x^{2}-4} = 4\\
\int \frac{1}{x^{2}-4} dx = \int 4 dt 
\end{equation}

### Edit 2:

Can I then denote my solution as:

$x(t) = \frac{2(e^{4c_{1}+16t})}{(e^{4c_{1}-16t})}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation ${\dot{x}\over x^2-4}=4$ is actually equivalent to $${{dx\over dt}\over x^2-4}=4$$which, by multiplying both sides in $dt$ leads to $${dx\over x^2-4}=4dt$$or$$\int{dx\over x^2-4}=\int 4dt$$

Comment: and the integral is with regards to $t$ right?

Comment: Not both of them. The right one is with respect to $t$ while the left one is with respect to $x$.

Comment: @ThamuMnyulwa: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation.

Comment: Can I interpret the solution as specified in my second edit?

Comment: Your Edit 1 sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

They divided both sides of the equation by the term $x^2-4$ and then took the integral.

Comment: @ GSofer , thank you for your answer. Is the integration step performed as I stated above in the edit?