# Integrate both side of a partial derivate equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

With x and y being independent variables, if:

$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial x}$

Is it correct to assume that:

$\int\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}dt = \int\frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial x}dx \iff f(x,t) = g(x,t)$

?

Comment: It's rather obviously *not* correct. Have you tested your theory on some simple examples?

Comment: You are right, I have seen this kind of things with finite integrals in EDP solving though. I am trying to understand how and when exactly we can do this kind of thing.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the method of separation of variables for ordinary differential equations? That's just the chain rule backwards; see for example this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation.

Comment: It was in wave equations solving using the caracteristic method for 2nd order EDP, but I think I made a huge shortcut in the way I asked my question. I'll upload a more precise example when I'm back home later today.

Comment: OK. (By the way, in English the abbreviation is PDE rather than EDP.)