How to solve the ODEs $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=5y^2$, in an appropriate way?
This is a simple question, that was asked as a trap in an interview.
The expert asked to solve the 1st order ode $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2$.
Recalling my undergraduate classes, without double thinking I started to separate the variables (inspired by the method of separation of variables) as follows:
\begin{align} &\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2 \\
\Rightarrow & dy=5x^2dx \\ \Rightarrow & \int dy=5\int x^2dx+c,~\text{c is an arbitrary constant} \end{align}
This is where the expert raised objection by saying that "how can we multiply $dx$"? The expert said "Do you mean $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a ratio?"
I said NO, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not ratio but a limit of infinitesimal increment of $y$ with respect to $x$. That is, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. I also said this I am following the method of separation of variables. But the expert was stick to the  question, that is, how I multiplied $dx$. However, at that moment, I failed to explain the above method of solution of the ODE, that is, I failed to explain how I obtained $dy=5x^2dx$, I was repeating the name of the method. At that moment, I was thinking that this question was a trap question.
Later, I have thought of what could have been explained.
I realized that I should followed the following approach instead:
\begin{align} &\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2 \\
 \Rightarrow & \int (\frac{dy}{dx})dx=5\int x^2dx+c,~\text{c is an arbitrary constant} \\
\Rightarrow & \int y'(x)dx=5\int x^2dx+c,~(\text{since}~y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}) \\
\Rightarrow & \int dy=5\int x^2dx+c 
\end{align}
Suppose I was asked to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=5y^2$ (instead of $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2)$, then I should have rewritten it as $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{5y^2}$ and then operate $dy$ both sides and take integration, that is to follow my second approach above.
I appreciate opinions/advice from experts. What should be the correct approach to answer such questions. Is my second approach correct?

My intuitive understanding is to view $x,y$ as a function of $t$, then the multiplication is granted by chain rule, and this also explains why for higher derivative, you cannot separate and multiply the differential.

@AngaeMT, I guess, you are considering parametric form. What about the second approach above? Is that correct?

Which is the level of the exam and what kind of an examination is this one? (Differential equations, mechanics, applied mathematics, simple integration techniques, exact forms are known...?)

@dan_fulea, it was an interview for undergraduate level teaching. My subject was not differential equation though. I preferred geometry. But still asked this question.

The question is placed in the context of "differential equations and solutions", and in this case the problem of solving the ODE$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$$(in this generality) has a formal character, it is a kind of notation, and solving means finding a function $y=y(x)$ (again a formal notation that taken strictly makes no sense) which is defined "somewhere" (on an open interval) and so that on the full domain of definition of $y$ we have the identity / equality of functions $$y'(x)=f(x,y(x))\ .$$This is one kind of object. When writing formally the object $$dy -5x^2; dx$$the question

...the question of the examiner is a standard question "what kind of object is this one", unfortunately the question comes in "plain language" for the "equality"$$dy = 5x^2; dx$$which as it stays is no longer a "good object". But in the formalism it is ok to write it like this and claim that we shall "integrate on both side in a formal manner". The connection between the two kinds of questions: Solving $y'(x)=5x^2$ (simple integration) and showing explicitly that the (closed) one-form $dy-5x^2; dx$ is exact are two equivalent problems, in this one case the integration is simpler.

@dan_fulea, this could be an appropriate answer. Why don't you write it as an answer?

The question of the examiner is half a helping question, but half an irritating question. If you have never seen $1$-forms, it is less probable that a good answer can be given. The question was more or less "what kind of an object is $$5x^2; dx\ ?$$In other words, you multiply something with $dx$, which is the sense of the object? Does it come from a ratio? The question is only trying to see how far the knowledge goes. Repeatedly saying "i am doing what we always did when applying the method of separation of variables" (although already separated) is ok, and the examiner should quit asking.

@dan_fulea, yes, it is difficult to follow what was in the mind of the examiner? Although, his previous questions were simple like this, I mean he was quickly skimming over algebra, geometry, numerical analysis and finally differential equation. He just said "solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2$. Only two words. Later I checked his profile, he was from applied math background. I am not sure if he was interested in "1-forms", at least he never worked/taught exterior algebras or differential geometry.  It seems the question was rather simple, he was checking if I can proceed correctly with explanation

You may try to answer yourself the own question, this is the best way to take the exam! People will comment again, and from the new comments you will learn more then a foreign answer! Please try to answer the question, more exactly how to pass from the formal $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$$ (which is a differential equation) to "solving" / integrating the one form $$dy-f(x,y); dx$$. It is a theorem more or less, at any rate we are not "multiplying with $dx$", although we formally do so. Try to find a reference, to understand what is a $1$-form (and a $2$-form...) and to build sentences...

@dan_fulea, alright looking forward to write an self-answer

We will never know what the examiner had in mind, often the examination is just a dialog, and from the way things evolve - although not dry and well defined at any step - the final image, but sometimes not some in between situation, is speaking for a sound, solid knowledge. (It is good possible that the examiner will not face herself or himself the question with bravery if self in the position to be examined, but getting out of the situation in a consistent manner is in such cases the main task, always mention what is part of notation, convention, formalism, and isolate the structure.)

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation

@dan_fulea, can you check the Edit of my answer below which you asked to show? Is it a valid answer or should I ask this as a new question for further inputs?

I would denote $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$, even though it is not necessary to introduce this notation.
We can notice that $y' = 5 y^2$ has a constant solution, namely $y=0$. Then we can divide by $y$ both sides:
$$
\frac{y'}{y^2} = 5  
$$
Now we can integrate both sides and we get
$$
- \frac{1}{y} = 5 x + c, 
$$
namely
$$y = - \frac{1}{5x+c}$$

With the help and advice of @dan_fulea, I am trying to answer this question as follows:
Formally, we can solve the ode $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2$ as follows:
\begin{align} &\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2 \\ &\text{Let's integrate with respect to $x$} \\ & \int \frac{dy}{dx} dx=5 \int x^2dx+c,~(\text{$c$ is arbitrary constant}) \\
\Rightarrow &\int dy=5 \int x^2dx+c,~(\text{by chain rule $dy=\frac{dy}{dx}dx$}) \\
\Rightarrow &y=\frac{5}{3}x^3+c\end{align}
However, to solve a general ode $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$, the idea is to consider the equivalent (${\color{red}{\text{to be explained later}}}$) 1-form $dy-f(x,y)dx$ such that its integral vanishes. In general,
a 1-form $\omega$ is of the form $\omega=M(x,y)dx-N(x,y)dy$, where $M,N$ are continuously differentiable. In this case $M(x,y)=f(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)=1$. The 1-form $\omega$ is exact, if we can express it as
$$\omega=d(u),~\text{where $u$ is a smooth function of $x,y$}.$$
In an equivalent way to check if $\omega$ is exact, just check if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$.
Thus, taking integral: $$\int \omega=u+c,$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. Since we have a zero on RHS of $dy-f(x,y)dx=0$, the solution  is $u+c=0$.
If $\omega$ is not exact, we need to multiply by a function $\mu(x,y)$, say, which is called integrating factor. This will make the 1-form exact and we can solve as before.
So we return back to our original question $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^2$, whose equivalent to the 1-form $$\omega=dy-5x^2dx.$$ This is exact, easily can be checked. Indeed, $\omega=d(y-\frac{5}{3}x^3)=d(u)$, where $u= y-\frac{5}{3}x^3$. Thus the solution is $y-\frac{5}{3}x^3=c$, i.e., $y=\frac{5}{3}x^3+c$.
Edit: I am still not clear why would solving the ode $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)~\longrightarrow (*)$$ be equivalent to integration of the $1$-form $dy-f(x,y)dx$ vanishes along the solution curve. But by chain rule or by the property of a differential of the $0$-form $y(x)$,
\begin{align}
&dy(x)=y'(x)dx \\ \text{i.e.,}~&
dy=\frac{dy}{dx}dx~\longrightarrow (**) \end{align}
Substituting $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from $(*)$ and puting it in $(**)$, we obtain
$$dy=f(x,y)dx \Rightarrow dy-f(x,y)dx=0.$$
That is, the $1$-form $dy-f(x,y)dx$ vanishes when we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$. Now integrating the $1$-form $dy-f(x,y)dx$ will give the integral curve.
Is this something happening, when we say the words

solving the ode $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ be
equivalent to integration of the $1$-form $dy-f(x,y)dx$ vanishes along
the solution curve

